# Get time difference of two dates using awk

Tags: awk, perl, date

I have a file of size 7GB. Now have two date time in that I want to use awk to get this difference of time between that two DateTime.

Below is how my files look like:

```
A          B      C      D         E
18/06/28 09:19:07 295  141536 18-06-28 09:17:47
18/06/28 09:20:07 268  1160   18-06-28 09:18:58
18/06/28 09:21:07 317  1454   18-06-28 09:19:47
18/06/28 09:22:07 275  1491   18-06-28 09:20:59
18/06/28 09:23:07 320  1870   18-06-28 09:21:07
18/06/28 09:24:07 310  1869   18-06-28 09:22:30
18/06/28 09:25:07 150   693   18-06-28 09:23:28
18/06/28 09:26:07 414  2227   18-06-28 09:24:34
```

I want the difference between (AB) - (E).

I tried this :

```
cat filename | awk -F " " '{print date -d ($1$2)-($5)}'
```

Output should be the time difference between the two datetime. Like for the first row difference will be 1min 20sec

Comment: your desired result format?

Comment: time difference output will be 02:40 for the first row

Comment: Why specifically in `awk` and then why adding the `perl` tag?

Comment: Please don't clarify with comments; edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @glennjackman I did it my mistake you are correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
gawk '
  function dt2epoch(date, time,      timestr) {
    timestr = "20" substr(date,1,2) " " substr(date,4,2) " " substr(date,7,2) \
               " " substr(time,1,2) " " substr(time,4,2) " " substr(time,7,2)
    return mktime(timestr)
  }
  function epoch2hms(t) {
    return strftime("%H:%M:%S", t, 1)
  }
  function abs(n) {return n<0 ? -1*n : n}
  NR == 1 {next}
  { print epoch2hms(abs(dt2epoch($5,$6) - dt2epoch($1,$2))) }
' file
```

outputs

```
00:01:20
00:01:09
00:01:20
00:01:08
00:02:00
00:01:37
00:01:39
00:01:33
```

---

with perl, I'd use the [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) ecosystem:

```
perl -MDateTime::Format::Strptime -lane '
    BEGIN {$f = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
    next if $. == 1;
    $F[0] =~ s{/}{-}g;
    $t1 = $f->parse_datetime("$F[0] $F[1]");
    $t2 = $f->parse_datetime("$F[4] $F[5]");
    $d = $t1->subtract_datetime($t2);
    printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", $d->hours, $d->minutes, $d->seconds;
' file
```

---

A much faster perl version, that does not require any non-core modules

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lane '
    next if $. == 1;
    $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime("$F[0] $F[1]", "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S");
    $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime("$F[4] $F[5]", "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    $diff = gmtime(abs($t1->epoch - $t2->epoch));
    print $diff->hms;
' file
```

or, alternate output:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -lane '
    next if $. == 1;
    $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime("$F[0] $F[1]", "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S");
    $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime("$F[4] $F[5]", "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    print abs($t1 - $t2)->pretty;
' file
1 minutes, 20 seconds
1 minutes, 9 seconds
1 minutes, 20 seconds
1 minutes, 8 seconds
2 minutes, 0 seconds
1 minutes, 37 seconds
1 minutes, 39 seconds
1 minutes, 33 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` and `awk` combined:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 {print $1,$2,$5,$6}' input  | while read d1 t1 d2 t2; do
  i1=$(date -u -d "20$d1 $t1" +%s)
  i2=$(date -u -d "20$d1 $t2" +%s)
  date -d @"$((i1-i2))" +%M:%S; 
done
01:20
01:09
01:20
01:08
02:00
01:37
01:39
01:33
```

Comment: I think this will be extremely slow for a huge input file, calling out to date for every line.

Comment: It might, but then both of our solutions do a whole passel of string comparisons.  It'd also be doable, but a larger lift, to actually leverage `awk` with `FS=/[\s/:-]/`and doing all the arithmetic "by hand".

Comment: `date -d` and `date +%s` are both proprietary extensions.

Comment: GNU is proprietary now?  And I've never seen an implementation of `date` that didn't have output format strings.

Answer (score 1):

benchmarking: I duplicated your sample data a whole bunch of times

```
$ wc -l file
131073 file
```

Now some timing:

```
$ time  awk 'NR>1 {print $1,$2,$5,$6}' file |
while read d1 t1 d2 t2; do
  i1=$(date -u -d "20$d1 $t1" +%s)
  i2=$(date -u -d "20$d1 $t2" +%s)
  date -d @"$((i1-i2))" +%M:%S
done > /dev/null

real    8m55.533s
user    5m46.956s
sys     1m33.726s
```

```
$ time perl -MDateTime::Format::Strptime -lane '
    BEGIN {$f = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
    next if $. == 1;
    $F[0] =~ s{/}{-}g;
    $t1 = $f->parse_datetime("$F[0] $F[1]");
    $t2 = $f->parse_datetime("$F[4] $F[5]");
    $d = $t1->subtract_datetime($t2);printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", $d->hours, $d->minutes, $d->seconds;
' file > /dev/null

real    0m37.684s
user    0m33.168s
sys     0m0.058s
```

```
$ time gawk '
  function dt2epoch(date, time,      timestr) {
    timestr = "20" substr(date,1,2) " " substr(date,4,2) " " substr(date,7,2) \
               " " substr(time,1,2) " " substr(time,4,2) " " substr(time,7,2)
    return mktime(timestr)
  }
  function epoch2hms(t) {
    return strftime("%H:%M:%S", t, 1)
  }
  function abs(n) {return n<0 ? -1*n : n}
  NR == 1 {next}
  { print epoch2hms(abs(dt2epoch($5,$6) - dt2epoch($1,$2))) }
' file > /dev/null

real    0m1.074s
user    0m0.610s
sys     0m0.366s
```

GNU awk, with the built-in time functions is the clear winner, even with all the string manipulation.

---

Update: new perl implementation. Still slower than gawk, but miles ahead of the version using the feature-rich but heavyweight DateTime module:

```
$ time perl -MTime::Piece -lane '
    next if $. == 1;
    $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime("$F[0] $F[1]", "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S");
    $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime("$F[4] $F[5]", "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    $diff = gmtime(abs($t1->epoch - $t2->epoch));
    print $diff->hms;           
' file > /dev/null

real    0m2.631s
user    0m2.231s
sys     0m0.170s
```

Comment: The `perl` solution seems to be the only portable solution.

Comment: Now it's even more portable: only using [core module Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html).